# Can program detect when Windows New Hardware Wizard is running (USB device connect)

Tags: windows, usb, hardware, wizard

Is there some way for a user-space program to reliably detect when the Windows New Hardware Wizard is active and blocking access to a new USB device?

Background: whenever I connect a new "Teensy 3.1" (Arduino-compatible ARM Coretex-M4 board) to a Windows 7 computer via USB, it triggers the Windows "Found New Hardware" Wizard and a USB enumeration process and search for drivers ensues, taking often > 10 seconds during which the USB device is blocked from user software.  This causes the "Teensyduino" host PC software troubles which the Teensy developer (Paul Stoffregen at pjrc.com) mentions do not occur on his other supported platforms (Mac, Linux) but could be mitigated if there was a reliable way of detecting when the New Hardware Wizard is active.

Note this question is specific to userspace visibility of the Windows Hardware Wizard process, and is distinct from other questions about simply detecting if a USB device has been connected.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a slight modification to your approach: "Found New Hardware" doesn't give you actionable information, since that same wizard appears for many different devices.  On the other hand, after enumeration and before driver installation (driver identification and installation is the slow part), a device node appears that already has the correct VID and PID associated to it.  So you should use the usual methods, but also look for devices categorized as unknown, and not just serial-port or mass-storage or whatever final driver you want.

Comment: If you find the matching device, you can tell something about driver install progress by querying the DEVPKEY_Device_InstallState property.  Possible values listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543130(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, the InstallState info looks useful.